# Image Upload with Multipart Request from Android Volley to PHP

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am sending a parameters from my android app to php for the purpose of image upload using `SimpleMultiPartRequest` as follows:

```
smr.addStringParam("userid", userid);
smr.addStringParam("caption", caption);
```

I tried accessing the parameters`userid` and `caption` in php using `$_POST[]` but returns an empty response.

### Help needed on which method to use in php to access the above variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do know about SimpleMultiPartRequest but I am sending my data by json object and catch at php by following code in php.
try this if work.

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($data,TRUE);  

$userid = $json["userid"];
$caption = $json["caption"];
```